# Use PostgreSQL builtin operator <@ after including extension intarray

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, array

I added the [intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/intarray.html) extension to my PostgreSQL database in order to make use of the `-` operator, but I still want to use the **builtin** `<@` operator, not **intarray's** `<@` operator. Is there a way to do this?

The reason to prefer the builtin operator is that the **builtin** operator allows `NULL` values in the array in question, whereas the **intarray** operator raises an error in the event of a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed the `intarray` extension to the `public` schema (or some schema other than `pg_catalog`), you can schema-qualify the operator to choose the built-in one.

Instead of

```
a <@ b
```

you can write

```
a OPERATOR(pg_catalog.<@) b
```

to schema-qualify it.

e.g.

```
test=# SELECT 1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.+) 2;
 ?column? 
----------
        3
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

[What @Craig wrote.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/110610/3684)

Plus, to find which extensions are installed where:

```
SELECT n.nspname, e.extname
FROM   pg_extension e
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = e.extnamespace;
```

Result:

```
nspname    | extname
-----------+----------
pg_catalog | plpgsql
public     | intarray
public     | btree_gist
...
```

Be aware that a schema-qualified operator (`OPERATOR(pg_catalog.<@)`) has  **default operator precedence** (loses any special status). Does not change anything for `<@` because it has default operator precedence to begin with. [Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE)

---

Finally, since the operator installed by `intarray` only works for `integer[]` while the default operator works for `anyarray`, a quick and dirty way to get default behavior is to cast the `integer` array to a `bigint` array:

```
SELECT a::bigint[] <@ b::bigint[]
```

`a` and `b` being of type `int[]`. You could use `real[]`, `float[]`, `numeric[]` or `text[]` as well, all of them work.

Details:

```
SELECT n.nspname, o.oprname, o.oprleft::regtype, o.oprright::regtype
FROM   pg_operator o
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = o.oprnamespace
WHERE  oprname = '<@'
AND   (oprleft::regtype::text  ~~ '%any%' OR
       oprleft::regtype::text  ~~ '%integer%');
```

Result:

```
nspname    | oprname | oprleft    | oprright
-----------+---------+------------+----------
pg_catalog | <@      | anyrange   | anyrange
pg_catalog | <@      | anyelement | anyrange
pg_catalog | <@      | anyarray   | anyarray
public     | <@      | integer[]  | integer[]
```