# Is it possible to schema-qualify an operator?

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgis, operator

Let's say I create an extension, like PostGIS, in the schema `postgis`,

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis WITH SCHEMA postgis;
```

Is it possible to fully qualify an operator like `&&` in the below example,

```
SELECT box2d && ST_MakePoint(5,5)
FROM postgis.box2d(postgis.ST_MakeEnvelope(0,0,10,10));
```

But `"postgis.&&"` and even `"postgis".&&` and `"postgis"."&&"` is not working for me. The [docs on "Operator Type Resolution" seem to hint at being possible](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-oper.html),

> If a qualified operator name was given, only operators in the specified schema are considered.

Put another way, can I use an operator that [is "*not* visible".](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html)

```
SELECT pg_type_is_visible(
  'postgis.&&(postgis.geometry,postgis.geometry)'::regoperator
);
```

Clearly, I can add `postgis` to my `search_path` but I'm looking to leave that unmodified and in ever other context we can in fact qualify everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [it's documented under The Schema Search Path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) with `OPERATOR()`

```
SELECT box2d OPERATOR(postgis.&&) postgis.ST_MakePoint(5,5) AS "&&"
FROM postgis.box2d(postgis.ST_MakeEnvelope(0,0,10,10));
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the `OPERATOR` construct (like `OPERATOR(postgis.&&)`) is ***not 100 % identical*** to the operator itself. Operators lose their implicit precedence and fall back to ***[default operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE)***, which can have sneaky side effects. Consider:

```
SELECT 3 + 3 * 2                        -- 9
     , 3 + 3 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.*) 2;  -- 12
```

There is no effect for `OPERATOR(postgis.&&)` as `&&` has default operator precedence to begin with.

Related:

- [Use PostgreSQL builtin operator <@ after including extension intarray](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110599/use-postgresql-builtin-operator-after-including-extension-intarray/110650)
- [GIN index on smallint[] column not used or error “operator is not unique”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798993/gin-index-on-smallint-column-not-used-or-error-operator-is-not-unique/39802812#39802812)

Another limitation: the `OPERATOR` construct does not work for SQL syntax elements like `AND`, `OR`, `BETWEEN` etc., which are also sometimes called "operators" (and have their own operator precedence). Only for operators listed in the system catalog [`pg_operator`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-operator.html).